# How to create such type of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var data = [{"label":"Category A", "value":20}, 
            {"label":"Category B", "value":50}, 
            {"label":"Category C", "value":30}];
```

how to create these array dynamically and such type of array's are called as ?

Comment: can you explain your question more clearly?

Answer (score 2):

just try this:

```
var data=[];
data.push({'label':category,'value':newVal});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are making this array from some value, try this:

```
  var myData =[];
  myData.push({lable:yourlabel,value:yourValue});
```

you can loop through a data set and set yourlabel and your values in it

Answer (score 1):

```
var data=[];

data.push({"label":"Category A", "value":20}); // push as many element you want by comma separated
```

These type of arrays are called as collection/ array of objects